# Escape colon in XML element names when using json_encode

Tags: php, json, xml

I'm trying to convert simple XML to a multi-dimensional array by using the following method.

```
$json = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xmlstring, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA)), true);
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

This works okay but some of the nodes in my XML have names with colon's in them, for example

```
<things>
    <thing:Food>
        <food:fruit>79</food:fruit>
    </thing:Food>
</things>
```

When I do the `json_encode` these nodes are removed, presumably because it thinks anything either side of a colon is a key value pair.

I can't change the structure of the XML so does anyone know a way round this problem?

I'm using PHP version 5.5.29 on OSX

Comment: You have a parse error and not valid XML, but if you ignore that the `:` don't present a problem here.

Comment: I get this JSON: `string(34) "{"thing:Food":{"food:fruit":"79"}}"`

Comment: What happens if you just do `simplexml_load_string()` alone? Do you get a valid object? You should also include the top of the XML file that includes the namespace declarations.

Comment: @miken32 yes it's valid

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? And what OS? Debian distros have a weird non-standard version of the JSON extension, at least in PHP 5.5, possibly others.

Comment: @miken32 updated question with this info

Comment: Can't reproduce on OS X PHP 5.5.36. Output here: http://pastebin.com/SSzkMkXH

Comment: @miken32 True but you're doing the json_encode on a manually typed string rather than the output of `simplexml_load_string()`.  The string you typed is "{"thing:Food":{"food:fruit":"79"}}" but I suspect the `thing:Food isn't escaped in quotes

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm starting with the XML you provided.

Comment: @miken32 Ah sorry, I misread it

Comment: @Pattle, can you provide the complete `xml` string?